# Get position of 3 seperate divs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, dom, coordinates, getboundingclientrect

I have 3 divs, which I'm displaying in a ReactJS app.
I'm displaying the divs, by looping through an object of classNames stored in state.  (Each className has it's own CSS styling, which displays a color - hat1, hat2, hat3).

OnClick, I want to get the div coordinates/position of any of the 3 divs I click on.

I've tried using `React.createRef()` and `getBoundingClientRect()`. However, both methods give me the same coordinates, no matter which div I click on.

It looks like it's returning the coordinates of the `<section>` tag, rather than the target div element I click on...

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Cylinders extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      divs: [
        { 
          className: 'hat1'
        },
        { 
          className: 'hat2'
        },
        { 
          className: 'hat3'
        }
      ]
    }
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('mount');
  }

  handleClick = (item, i) => {
    console.log('item', item);
    console.log('i', i);

    var divCoordinates = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(divCoordinates, 'divCoordinates');

   // const node = this.myRef.current;
   // console.log('node', node);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <section>

          <div className="columns is-mobile">
            <div className="column">
              <h1 className="title has-text-black is-size-2">Cylinders Game</h1>
              <button className="has-text-black">Ball container</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="columns is-mobile">
            <div className="colum ballContainer">
              <div className="ball"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="columns is-mobile">

            {this.state.divs.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <div className="column">
                  <div className="columns is-multiline">
                    <div
                      onClick={() => this.handleClick(item, i)}
                      className={item.className}
                      key={item.name + i}
                      ref={el => this.containerLine = el}
                    > {i}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })}

          </div>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Cylinders;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working!

I simply targeted the item, with `item.target`.

```
var divCoordinates = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(item.target).getBoundingClientRect();
```